# Autoload PSR-4 namespacing interface not found in

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php

```
{ 
       "autoload": {

       "psr-4": {
        "Acme\\": "src"
    }
}
}
```

my composer.json file

```
namespace Acme;

Interface Responds
{   
    public function userRegisteredSuccessfuly();

    public function userRegisteredunSuccessfuly();  
}
```

The Interface is located on C:\xampp\htdocs\bootcamp\src\respondstouserregistration.php

```
<?php 
namespace Acme;

class RegisterUser
{
    public function execute(array $data, Responds $listener) //data 
    {
        var_dump('registering the user.');
        $listener->userRegisteredSuccessfuly();
    }
}
```

In the RegisterUser i referenced the interface responds, registeruser is also located in src

```
<?php 
namespace Acme;

class AuthController implements Responds
{
    protected $registration;

    public function __construct(RegisterUser $registration)
    {
        $this->registration = $registration;
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $this->registration->execute([], $this);
    }

    public function userRegisteredSuccessfuly()
    {
        var_dump('created successfuly. redirect somewhere.');
    }


    public function userRegisteredunSuccessfuly()
    {
        var_dump('created unsuccessfuly. redirect back.');
    }

}
```

And in this class i implemented the responds interface.

The AuthController is also located on C:\xampp\htdocs\bootcamp\src\authcontroller.php

Now my error is

> PHP Fatal error: Interface 'Acme\Responds' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\bootcamp\src\authcontroller.php
>   How can i make the Authcontroller locate the php file where the interface is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PSR-4 Autoloading assumes your classname matches the filename. So your `Interface Responds` is expected to be in a `responds.php` file, not in a `respondstouserregistration.php` file. Either rename the file, or rename your interface to `Interface Respondstouserregistration`